# IOS:multiple arrays display on a single Tableview

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

In my project i have 2 `UITableViews`.
TableView 1 have fields - Physician, Diagnose, Procedure.
I just want that when i select Physician from UITableView 1 the other `tableView2` `UITableView` 2 displays the Value of Physician.
like this when i select Diagnose from `UITableView` 1 the other `tableView` `UITableView` 2 displays the Value of Diagnose.
Can any one have any idea regarding this.

Comment: It will be very helpful if just add some code  & screenshots here

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: In the delegate itself compare the tableView object/tag/identifier and use array1 or array2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is my suggest:

You need two `NSMutableArray *a_arr, *b_arr,`

The a_arr    show  all keys for the  `NSDic`,

The b_arr    show  which  keys to  arr  infomation

When you select `A  table`, at the method:

```
 tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath




b_arr      objiectforkey: (a table select key);

and the table B  use  the  b_arr  data ,

then :

table B  reloadData
```

Answer (score 3):

You can have either two different delegates for both the table or even same object as delegate for both tables.

In delegate method tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath: check for the table=table1 and based on the row selected, update the datasource of table2 and reload table2.

Answer (score 1):

> Assign tags to tableViews, then compare tag and use specific arrays
>   for different tableViews.